# Angular 4 | Error in production ng2-linq

Tags: angular, linq

I am  having an error when I build my angular 2 app.

it says,

> ERROR in ./node_modules/ng2-linq/ng2-linq.ts Module failed: Error D:\voice\my-app\node_modules\ng2-linq\ng2-linq.ts is not part of the compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the'files' or 'include' property.

How can i fix this?

Comment: error says it better.

Comment: so how can i call linq on tsconfig file?

Comment: pl check the files and include section. this should help. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be happening because you were using ng2-linq outside the src folder. To resolve this issue include the file name (where you are using ng2-linq) in tsconfig.app.json and also in tsconfig.spec.json.

```
"include": [
    "path of that file."
]
```

Hope this works for you!!

Comment: i use linq on my app.components.ts and it is located on node_modules/ng2-linq and i call it this way.. import { LinqService } from 'ng2-linq'; however in the instructions on npm should be import { LinqService } from `'./ng2-linq'`; but im getting error locating the linq

Comment: Import it as follow:
import { LinqService } from 'ng2-linq/ng2-linq';

If still, you face the problem, please share your code.

Comment: i solve it by deleting my ng2-linq.ts, i thinnk it was already compiled when i downloaded it, thats why it prompt me an error that ng2-linq is not part  of the compilation.

Comment: Ohh, that's great.